# How to get rid of System Volume Information on non-root folder?

Tags: windows

I mounted my OneDrive folder as a drive, so Microsoft thought it has to create the “System Volume Information” folder in there.

So far, so good, and actually understandable, but then I changed my mind and I unmounted the folder as a drive and let it be a regular folder under my user folder.

Unfortunately “System Volume Information” stuck.

Anyone knows how can I delete it, but preferably by making Windows remove it, rather than taking ownership of the folder and brute-force my way to destruction with unknown consequences?

Comment: It might be possible through Windows, by assigning back the drive letter, taking ownership of the folder, deleting it, and immediately unassigning the drive letter.